# Сортировка товаров по категории categoryId в XML файле

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Есть XML:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">
<yml_catalog date="2017-12-27 12:13">
    <shop>
        <name>Agrosfera</name>
        <company>Agrosfera</company>
        <url>http://agrosfera.ua/</url>
        <currencies>
            <currency id="UAH" rate="1"/>
        </currencies>
        <categories>
            <category id="61">Средства защиты растений</category>
            <category id="62">Микроудобрения</category>
            <category id="63">Инсектицид</category>
        </categories>
        <offers>
            <offer id="10051" available="true">
                <url>http://agrosfera.ua/catalog/sredstva-zahiti/inset-10155</url>
                <price>1235</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>63</categoryId>
                <picture>http://agrosfera.ua/tmp/cache/images/f6a2c2622d2bd4e5a6547217047fdea0.Inset_Blue_Pack.jpg</picture>
                <vendor>Agrosfera</vendor>
                <name>Инсектицид Agrosfera Ин Сет   10155 1 кг фольгированный пакет (10 пакетов по 100 г)</name>
                <description>
                    <![CDATA[<p style="text-align:justify">Ин&nbsp;Сет, ВГ - высокоэффективный, и один из самых безопасных для окружающей среды.</p>]]>
                </description>
                <param name="Метод применения">
                    <![CDATA[При наземном применении]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Вредители">
                    <![CDATA[Клоп, пыльщик, рапсовый цветоед, колорадский жук, яблоневая плодожорка и другие]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Срок применения">
                    <![CDATA[Протравливание семян до посева]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Вес, г">
                    <![CDATA[1 кг]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Тип">
                    <![CDATA[Инсектицид]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Действующее вещество">
                    <![CDATA[Имидаклоприд, 700 гкг]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Норма внесения">
                    <![CDATA[0,05-0,07 кгга]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Культура">
                    <![CDATA[Пшеница, рапс, картофель, яблоня, виноград]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Доставка">
                    <![CDATA[1-3 дня]]>
                </param>
            </offer>
            <offer id="1050" available="true">
                <url>http://agrosfera.ua/catalog/rost-regulators/aminofresh-1050</url>
                <price>4299</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>61</categoryId>
                <picture>http://agrosfera.ua/tmp/cache/images/60b0ad89a8ce9d25b90fa2a59fbe13c9.AminoFresh.jpg</picture>
                <vendor>Agrosfera</vendor>
                <name>Микроудобрение Agrosfera Амино Фреш  1050 10 л пластиковая канистра</name>
                <description>
                    <![CDATA[<p style="text-align:justify">Амино Фреш&nbsp;- регулятор роста на основе аминокислот.</p>]]>
                </description>
                <param name="Метод применения">
                    <![CDATA[Внекорневое питание]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Вес, г">
                    <![CDATA[10 кг]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Тип">
                    <![CDATA[Микроудобрение]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Действующее вещество">
                    <![CDATA[Незаменимые L-аминокислоты-10%, N-11%]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Норма внесения">
                    <![CDATA[0,5-1,0 кгга]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Культура">
                    <![CDATA[Кукуруза, подсолнечник, ячмень]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Доставка">
                    <![CDATA[1-3 дня]]>
                </param>
            </offer>
            <offer id="1058" available="true">
                <url>http://agrosfera.ua/catalog/rost-regulators/lehndfresh-1051</url>
                <price>2799</price>
                <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
                <categoryId>62</categoryId>
                <picture>http://agrosfera.ua/tmp/cache/images/20681d5fb70a8e8dec3b20d3db01fbe3.GumilandFresh.jpg</picture>
                <vendor>Agrosfera</vendor>
                <name>Регулятор роста Agrosfera Гумилэнд Фреш  1051 10 л пластиковая канистра</name>
                <description>
                    <![CDATA[<p>Гумилэнд Фреш&nbsp;-&nbsp;регулятор роста для растений на основе калиевой соли.</p>]]>
                </description>
                <param name="Метод применения">
                    <![CDATA[Внекорневое питание]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Вес, г">
                    <![CDATA[10 кг]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Тип">
                    <![CDATA[Регулятор роста]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Действующее вещество">
                    <![CDATA[Гуминовая кислота-10%, фульвовая кислота-5%, К2О-4%]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Норма внесения">
                    <![CDATA[1,0-3,0 лга]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Культура">
                    <![CDATA[Пшеница, ячмень, кукуруза, подсолнечник]]>
                </param>
                <param name="Доставка">
                    <![CDATA[1-3 дня]]>
                </param>
            </offer>
        </offers>
    </shop>
</yml_catalog>
```

Обрабатываю XML с помощью PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>xml</title>
<body>
<?php
//получаю хмл по ссылке
$url = $_POST["url"];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or exit("<br><br><br>&emsp;Нет связи с сервером xml");
//создаю цикл по товарам
foreach ($xml->shop->offers->offer as $offer) {

    $num = 1;
    $num2 = 1;
?>
                        <!--<h2>Товары</h2>-->
                        <!---вывод данных с xml в html будет таблица-->
                        <table border="1">
                        <!---цвет заглавнных колонок в таблице-->
                        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <!---названия заглавнных колонок таблицы-->
                        <th>Категория</th>
                        <th>Название товара</th>
                        <th>Производитель</th>
                        <th>Параметр и его значение</th>
                        <th>Фото товара</th> 
                        <th>Ссылки на товар и его фото</th>
                        <th>Описание</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Offer id</th>
                        <th>№</th>
                    </tr>
        <td> <?php 
        //вывожу название категории товара
        foreach ($xml->shop->categories->category as $category)
        {
        if( $count_category > 100 or count($all_offers) > 5000) {
        if ($category[id] == "$offer->categoryId"){echo $offer->categoryId. ' ::: '.$category . '<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>';break;}; 
        }
        else
        {
        $array_category_id[] = "$category[id]";
        $array_category333[] = "$category";
        if ($category[id] == "$offer->categoryId"){
        $parent222 = 0;
        for ($parent222 = 0; $parent222 < count($array_category_id); $parent222++){
        if($category[parentId] == $array_category_id[$parent222]) { echo $array_category333[$parent222].'<br>'.'<br>' ; break;};    
        }
        echo $offer->categoryId. ' ::: '.$category .'<br>'.'<br>';  
        }
        }

        }
        //вывожу наличие товара
        if($offer[available] == 'false' or empty($offer[available])) {echo '<br>'.'<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">'.$offer[available].'<br>'.'Товара нет в наличии.'.'</span>'.'<br>';} else {echo $offer[available];}
        if ($offer[аvailable] == 'false' or $offer[аvailable] == 'true' ){ echo '<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">'.'Слово available написано русскими буквами.'.'<br>'.$offer[аvailable].'</span>';};
        ?></td>
        <!-- Вывожу название товара --> 
    <td> <?php echo  $offer->name.'<br>'. '<br>'. '<br>' ; echo '<span style="color: blue; font-weight: bold;">'.$offer->model.'</span>';
    if(empty($offer->stock_quantity) or empty(strip_tags("$offer->stock_quantity"))) {} else {echo '<br>'.'<span style="color: Gray; font-weight: bold;">'.'Количество товара: '.$offer->stock_quantity.'</span>';}?></td>
    <!-- Вывожу производителя товара --> 
    <td> <?php echo  $offer->vendor.'<br>'. '<br>'. '<br>' ; ?></td>
    <!-- Вывожу параметры товара --> 
    <td> <?php foreach ($offer->param as $param) { echo $param['name']. ' ::: '. $param. '<br>'.'<br>'; } ?></td>
    <!-- Вывожу фото товара --> 
    <td> <?php foreach ($offer->picture as $picture) {echo("<img src='$picture' width='250' />").$num++.'<br>';} ?></td> 
    <!-- Вывожу ссылки на товар --> 
    <td>  <?php echo 'Ссылка на товар: '.'<br>';    echo("<a href='$offer->url' target='_blank'>$offer->url</a>"). '<br>'.'<br>';
    foreach ($offer->picture as $picture) { ;
    echo 'Ссылка на фото '.$num2++.':'. '<br>';
    echo("<a href='$picture' target='_blank'>$picture</a>"). '<br>'. '<br>'; } ?></td>
    <!-- Вывожу описание товара --> 
    <td> <?php echo $offer->description.'<br>' ; ?></td>
    <!-- Вывожу цену товара --> 
    <td> <?php echo $offer->price .' '. $offer->currencyId. '<br>'; ?></td>
    <!-- Вывожу номер оффер ид товара --> 
    <td> <?php echo $offer[id] ?></td>
    <!-- Вывожу порядковый номер товара --> 
<td> <?php print ++$number. '<br>' ; ?></td>

    <?php
    }

    ?>
        </table>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Вывод товаров из XML в страницу PHP производится в порядке записи товара в XML файле.
Как настроить вывод из XML в страницу PHP сортирую товары по категории `categoryId`?
Сначала товары 61 категории, потом товары 62 категории, потом товары 63 категории и т.д. Сейчас выводятся товары 63, 61, 62, так они написаны в XML, т.е без сортировки. Как правильно написать сортировку?
Как правильно прописать к такому XML файлу `usort` или `array_multisort`? Или как? Мало разбираюсь в этом.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит воспользоваться функцией сортировки массива [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

```
$like_xml= <<<XML
  <yml_catalog date="2017-12-27 12:13">
  <shop>
    <categories>
      <category id="63" name="Инсектицид" />
      <category id="61" name="Средства защиты растений" />
      <category id="62" name="Микроудобрения" />
    </categories>
    <offers>
      <offer id="10051" available="true">
         <categoryId>63</categoryId>  
      </offer>
      <offer id="1050" available="true">
         <categoryId>61</categoryId>  
      </offer>
      <offer id="1058" available="true">
         <categoryId>62</categoryId>  
      </offer>
    </offers>   
 </shop>
 </yml_catalog>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($like_xml);

$offers = $xml->xpath('/yml_catalog/shop/offers/offer');

function sortOffers($c1, $c2) {
    return strcmp($c1->categoryId, $c2->categoryId);
}

usort($offers, 'sortOffers'); // categoryId=61;categoryId=62;categoryId=63,etc.
```

[пример](http://jdoodle.com/a/j7b)

Comment: @Ваня обновил в ответе.

Comment: я написал print_r($offers); и оно выводит offer без сортировки по categoryId. Почему-то не работает.

Comment: @Ваня $offers = $xml->xpath('/shop/offers/offer'); этот путь соответствует дереву документа в примере, у вас структура немного другая. Обновил в ответе.

Comment: Вы просто расширили путь дописав yml_catalog, но все равно не сортирует. Когда Вы в своем примере допишите print_r($offers); у Вас происходит сортировка? Я беру просто Ваш ответ добавляю print_r($offers); чтоб посмотреть результат, но сортировка не происходит. Или что нужно писать в print_r для Вашего примера в ответе?

Comment: @Ваня jdoodle.com/a/j7b

Comment: Супер. Спасибо. Разобрался у меня версия php 5 стояла и в ней сортировка не работала. Поменял на 7 и все ок. Еще раз большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Ваня обновил в ответе. работает для php 5-7

Comment: а как Ваш пример реализовать в моем коде? я хмл получаю через $xml = simplexml_load_file($url). $url это ссылка на хмл файл с формы. Чтоб без $like_xml= <<<XML ... XML; Как необходимо Ваш пример преобразовать, чтоб вставить в мой код и чтоб сохранилась моя структура? Я так понимаю получаем хмл его сортируем, а потом уже дальше работает мой код вывода информации с хмл циклом foreach ($xml->shop->offers->offer as $offer) .

Comment: @Ваня В общем - да. Там, где у меня $xml = simplexml_load_string($like_xml); у вас будет $xml = simplexml_load_file($url). $xml - это объект класса SimpleXMLElement, не строка, ноды троки становятся свойствами. uasort производит сортировку и возвращает этот же объект, изменённый.